# Issue with webRTC one to one video chat not working when outside of the network

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on a small system which will include a one to one video chat. I am using scaledrone as they offer tutorials to get started and are good value. I have used pretty much what they have on their blog at https://www.scaledrone.com/blog/webrtc-tutorial-simple-video-chat/ which seems to work fine but now that I testing outside the network it seems the remote video does not work for either party, I also seem to have an issue from an ipad to a windows 10 laptop on Chrome or firefox.
Basically, it seems quiet patchy.
At times I get an error  DOMexception cannot add ice candidate when there is no remote sdp but sometimes, no error in the console but the video does not come across.
This is my first attempt at webRTC.
Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.scaledrone.com/scaledrone.min.js'></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 0 50px;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
    }
    video {
      max-width: calc(50% - 100px);
      margin: 0 50px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 0;
      box-shadow: rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px, rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 4px 4px, rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 8px 8px, rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 16px 16px, rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 32px 32px, rgba(156, 172, 172, 0.2) 0px 64px 64px;
    }
    .copy {
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      font-size: 16px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="copy">Send your URL to a friend to start a video call</div>
  <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
  <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay ></video>
  <script src="scripts/video.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Video.js:

```
 // Generate random room name if needed
if (!location.hash) {
  location.hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}
const roomHash = location.hash.substring(1);

// TODO: Replace with your own channel ID
const drone = new ScaleDrone('xxxx');
// Room name needs to be prefixed with 'observable-'
const roomName = 'observable-' + roomHash;
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};
let room;
let pc;


function onSuccess() {};
function onError(error) {
  console.error(error);
};

drone.on('open', error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  room = drone.subscribe(roomName);
  room.on('open', error => {
    if (error) {
      onError(error);
    }
  });
  // We're connected to the room and received an array of 'members'
  // connected to the room (including us). Signaling server is ready.
  room.on('members', members => {
    console.log('MEMBERS', members);
    // If we are the second user to connect to the room we will be creating the offer
    const isOfferer = members.length === 2;
    startWebRTC(isOfferer);
  });
});

// Send signaling data via Scaledrone
function sendMessage(message) {
  drone.publish({
    room: roomName,
    message
  });
}

function startWebRTC(isOfferer) {
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

  // 'onicecandidate' notifies us whenever an ICE agent needs to deliver a
  // message to the other peer through the signaling server
  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({'candidate': event.candidate});
    }
  };

  // If user is offerer let the 'negotiationneeded' event create the offer
  if (isOfferer) {
    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      pc.createOffer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
    }
  }

  // When a remote stream arrives display it in the #remoteVideo element
  pc.ontrack = event => {
    const stream = event.streams[0];
    if (!remoteVideo.srcObject || remoteVideo.srcObject.id !== stream.id) {
      remoteVideo.srcObject = stream;
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  }).then(stream => {
    // Display your local video in #localVideo element
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // Add your stream to be sent to the conneting peer
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
  }, onError);

  // Listen to signaling data from Scaledrone
  room.on('data', (message, client) => {
    // Message was sent by us
    console.log(message, client);
    if (client.id === drone.clientId) {
      return;
    }

    if (message.sdp) {
      // This is called after receiving an offer or answer from another peer
                      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), () => {
                                            // When receiving an offer lets answer it
                                            if (pc.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {
                                              pc.createAnswer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
                                            }
                      }, onError);
    } else if (message.candidate) {
      // Add the new ICE candidate to our connections remote description
          pc.addIceCandidate(
            new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate), onSuccess, onError
          );
    }
  });
}

function localDescCreated(desc) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(
    desc,
    () => sendMessage({'sdp': pc.localDescription}),
    onError
  );
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of connections will need `TURN server` to be added to the ICE servers.
Check [Coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver).

You can also create a free turn to test through [numb](https://numb.viagenie.ca/).